# Ruby on rails resource issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a project that includes lots of js, css and png. I couldn't divide them into javascripts and stylesheets folders. For example I have plugin1 folder it includes js and css files and I want to keep them together in same folder. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the rails assets pipeline Im nearly certain that you'll have to put the files into the correct location as described in the ruby guides. Rails will then pull all this together to create, for example, the js file. It would be, I imagine, a big job to change this set up.

I guess if your set on keeping the folders the same you'll just have to point to the JavaScript/CSS files the traditional way through the header/footer with links to the file locations.

The rails guides explain the asset pipeline pretty well, and are a good place to start digging around further.

Good luck!